# Garage door impulse generator volt free

Tags: voltage, current

I have a [NovoPort (PDF)](https://www.novoferm.com/fileadmin/novoferm_de/Dateien/tech-dok-PDFs/NovoPort-903010-55-6-50.pdf) garage door opener and I want to control the door with an ESP32. One of the issues I am having is the warning for "Do not connect any current-carrying cables". In the photo below I have a emergency stop sensor connected which connects to I (24V) and has an input to H.

1. If the input has to be volt-free how is this emergency sensor working?
2. I want to provide a second impulse generator (12F, illustration 12b) but I'm unsure how to provide a volt-free input

*Note:* There is a few versions of this opener, but they all appear to have the same requirements.

*Note:* The connections on the left (K) go to the motor.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

[image]

Comment: Use a relay ...

Comment: @brhans what is the existing sensor connecting if it has to be volt-free?

Answer (score 2):

That's just an odd way of specifying that you should only connect a bare contact closure to the input — in other words, the device you connect can either pass current between the two terminals or not, and it doesn't supply any voltage or current of its own. In normal use, you'd simply connect a pushbutton switch between the two terminals.

For automated operation, since this is AC, you could use either a relay or an AC-rated optoisolator.

Comment: Thanks Dave, how do you think the existing sensor is working as it's not linking two H pins (theirs a permanent metal link).

Comment: The doc says "an interruption at this input and end" but not sure as to what that means

Comment: Sounds like, NC (normally closed) switch, and When it opens/breaks the loop it activates.

Comment: Not sure how one input wire (white) could open the NC circuit?

Answer (score 0):

To add remote control to this, you would use a relay, and connect it to either NC (normal closed) or NO(normal open) depending on what it is looking for. then you would activate the relay with your ESP32.